# Ошибка при добавлении записей в таблицу

Tags: sql

Cоздал такую таблицу

```
CREATE TABLE fine(
        fine_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name VARCHAR(30),
        number_plate VARCHAR(6),
        violation VARCHAR(50),
        sum_fine DECIMAL(8,2),
        date_violation DATE,
        date_payment DATE
);
```

Но при добавлении записи я получаю ошибку, что я делаю не так?
вот код добавления

```
INSERT INTO fine(name, number_plate, violation, sum_fine, date_violation, date_payment)
VALUES ('Баранов П.Е.', 'Р523ВТ', 'Превышение скорости(от 40 до 60)', 500.00, '2020-01-12', '2020-01-17')

SELECT *
FROM fine
```

В общем разобрался - в моей субд нельзя одновременно обновлять таблицу и делать выборку, сделал пошагово, все заработало

Comment: Какую ошибку? .

Comment: @andreymal синтаксическая - 42000

Comment: А полный текст ошибки?

Comment: точку с запятой на конце выражения не забываешь?

Comment: @andreymal [Code: 42000, SQL State: 42000]  Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL "INSERT INTO FINE(NAME, NUMBER_PLATE, VIOLATION, SUM_FINE, DATE_VIOLATION, DATE_PAYMENT)
VALUES('Баранов П.Е.', 'Р523ВТ', 'Превышение скорости(от 40 до 60)', 500.00, '2020-01-12', '2020-01-17')

Comment: Это сообщение об ошибке не от MySQL, это интерпретация ошибки в Вашем клиенте или программе. Получите тот текст, который возвращает MySQL (например, посмотрите его в Error Log).

Answer (score 1):

Я предполагаю, что вы используете базу данных MySQL.

К каждому оператору SQL добавлена точка с запятой.

Проверьте это здесь: [DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/M3oj5Bal)